# How can I get the latitude and longitude of a vistor on my website?

Tags: php, location

I am researching ways of making ads actually relevant to people. How can I get the location of a visitor, who just loaded my page? I'm not talking `IP Geo-location`, I'm talking the exact latitude and longitude of a user, that I could later store in a database. Is there an `API` or something to allow me to get those values in `PHP` variables, using something like `GPS`?

Comment: This link is of help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864174/how-to-get-users-geolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First get visitor's location details from IP address**

**How to get user IP Address in PHP**

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
?>
```

**How to get user/ visitor Location in PHP**

```
<?php
require_once("userip/ip.codehelper.io.php");
require_once("userip/php_fast_cache.php");

$_ip = new ip_codehelper();

$real_client_ip_address = $_ip->getRealIP();
$visitor_location       = $_ip->getLocation($real_client_ip_address);

$guest_ip   = $visitor_location['IP'];
$guest_country = $visitor_location['CountryName'];
$guest_city  = $visitor_location['CityName'];
$guest_state = $visitor_location['RegionName'];

echo "IP Address: ". $guest_ip. "<br/>";
echo "Country: ". $guest_country. "<br/>";
echo "State: ". $guest_state. "<br/>";
echo "City: ". $guest_city. "<br/>";

?>
```

For more detail kindly visit below [link](http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/visitor-location-in-php)

Comment: For this files I have attached links kindly check